# table of tables using memoir

Tags: tables, memoir, subfloats

I need help to create a "table of tables" using `memoir`.
I'd like to use the `booktabs` features embedded in `memoir`.
What I'm trying to typeset is something like subfloats, having two 2x2 matrix of (small) tables inside the same page and having a main caption for the table and sigle captions for every table.
I was able to achieve it by using the `\newsubfloat{figure}` inside a figure enviroment and then using the `\subbottom` commands to add the tables.
However, the problem is the environment is not a table environment and then the labels and captions are not referring to tables.
How could I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\newsubfloat{table}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\subbottom[Table 1]{%
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
text & text \\
text & text \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{subt:1}%
}\hfill
\subbottom[Table 2]{%
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
text & text \\
text & text \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\label{subt:2}}\\
\subbottom[Table 3]{%
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
text & text \\
text & text \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{subt:3}%
}\hfill
\subbottom[Table 4]{%
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
text & text \\
text & text \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\label{subt:4}}
\caption{Table with four subtables} 
\label{fig:foursubtab}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]